# A counterexample for Sard's theorem in $C^1$ regularity

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, counterexamples

I can't seem to find an example of a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ which is $C^1$ and such that the set of its critical values is not of zero measure.

> What examples are there? 
>   $\phantom{aaa}$

Comment: Remark: the question originally asked by the OP asked about functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. An [edit (by another party?)](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/258141/2) changed the question to be about $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, which is why there are two different flavors of answers below, some addressing the original question, and some addressing the updated one.

Comment: I re-edited the question to its original form about functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 33):

My favourite  example is as follows. Let the simple curve $\kappa:[0,1]\to K\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a parametrization of (half of) the [Koch curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake), and let $\phi:K\to[0,1]$ be its inverse; it is a continuous function, and, due to the fact that $\kappa$ has infinite variation on any non-empty interval $J\subset [0,1]$, it *can be chosen in such a way that it* satisfies
$$|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|=o(|x-y|)$$
uniformly on $K$. Therefore the data $\phi$ together with the zero field on $K$ satisfy the hypotheses of the [Whitney extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) for the case of $C^1$ regularity. Thus $\phi$ extends to a  $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ whose gradient vanishes identically on $K$.

$$*$$
***Details.*** The standard parametrization of the Koch curve may be defined as the unique bounded function $\kappa:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ satisfying the (linear, non-homogeneous) functional equation

$$3\kappa(x)=\cases{\kappa(4x)& if  $\;0\le x< {1\over4}$\\\\
1+e^{i\pi/3}\kappa(4x-1)& if  $\;{1\over4}\le x< {2\over4}$\\\\
1+e^{i\pi/3}-e^{i\pi/3}\kappa(4x-2)& if  $\;{2\over4}\le x< {3\over4}$\\\\
2+\kappa(4x-3)& if  $\;{3\over4}\le x\le 1$}$$

that is $\kappa$ is the fixed point of an affine $1/3$-norm contraction on the Banach space of  $\mathbb{C}$-valued bounded functions on $[0,1]$, whence its existence and uniqueness. It also follows from this, that $\kappa$ is $\alpha$-Hölder, with $\alpha:={\log3\over\log4}$, and in fact, for some constants $0<c<C$ it verifies, for all $x$ and $y$ in $[0,1]$ 
$$c|x-y|^\alpha\le|\kappa(x)-\kappa(y)|\le C|x-y|^\alpha,$$

which implies that its inverse $\phi$ satisfies a Hölder condition with exponent $1/\alpha$, larger than $1$ (a phenomenon that is not possible for non-constant functions on an interval, or more generally on metric spaces connected by  rectifiable curves); in particular, it satisfies the stated  $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|=o(|x-y|)$.

Comment: Very interesting. I actually had not heard about Whitney's extension theorem (Tras. AMS 1934) before. It is a very neat analogue to Tietze-Urysohn extension theorem.

Comment: For generalizations of this example see https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1991757

Comment: $\kappa$ having infinite variation is not sufficient to get the estimate on $\phi$: build "one third" of the Koch snowflake starting from the trivial map $\gamma_0:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$ (with $\gamma_0(t)=(t,0)$), subdividing $[0,1]$ into three thirds and replacing the straight segment with a tent on the middle interval (thus obtaining $\gamma_1$), and so on. The limiting map $f_\infty:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$ will have $f_\infty(0)=(0,0)$ and $f_\infty(3^{-k})=(3^{-k},0)$! Maybe you are reparametrizing by arclength before taking the limit? (I don't know how to deal with $f_\infty$ in that case...)

Comment: Ah yes, now it's clear! So at each iteration you are reparametrizing by arclength, right? If you don't do that, having infinite variation *does not* give $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|=o(|x-y|)$ (this fails if you don't reparametrize by arclength, as I was saying in my previous comment).

Comment: (I edited and added details and rectified the unclear sentence about infinite variation. Thank you!)

Answer (score 30):

> If $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$, then the set of critical
> values may have positive measure.

The classical construction due to Whitney was mentioned in the answer by T. Amdeberhan. However, the simplest one is due to

**E.L.Grinberg,**
 [On the smoothness hypothesis in Sard's theorem.](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=77120&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=25&mx-pid=820057)
*Amer. Math. Monthly* 92 (1985), 733–734.

The idea is as follows:

If $C$ is the Cantor middle thirds set, then $C+C=[0,2]$.

There is a $C^1$ function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that the critical values of $g$ contain $C$.

Now $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=g(x)+g(y)$ is of class $C^1$ and $C+C=[0,2]$ is contained in the set of critical values of $f$.

Answer (score 21):

This has been known for some time, including the higher-dimensional problem, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that if $f\in C^k$ where $k<n$ then the set of critical points need not be of zero measure.

H.  Whitney,  *A function not  constant on  a  connected set  of  its  critical 
points*, Duke Math. J. **1** (1935), 514-517.

Answer (score 13):

I decided to challenge myself to make pictures of Piotr Hajlasz's example, partly for fun and partly for the next time I teach this. Let $C_3$ be the standard Cantor middle thirds set:
$$C_3 = \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{3^k} : a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots, \in \{ 0,2 \} \right\}.$$
Let $C_4$ be the variant "middle halves set"
$$C_4 = \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_k}{4^k} : b_1, b_2, b_3, \cdots, \in \{ 0,3 \} \right\}.$$
Note that every $z$ in $[0,1]$ can be written as $(2/3) x + (1/3) y$ for $x$, $y \in C_4$ in either $1$ or $2$ ways. Here is a drawing of $C_4 \times C_4$ and its intersection with the lines $(2/3)x + (1/3) y = k/16$ for $0 \leq k \leq 16$:

[image]

Here is a $C^1$ function $\phi(x)$ which maps $C_3$ to $C_4$ in an order preserving manner, with derivative $0$ at each point of $C_3$. On each interval of $[0,1] \setminus C_3$, it is an appropriately chosen sine curve.

[image]

And here is the final product, a depiction of the function $f(x,y) = (2/3) \phi(x) + (1/3) \phi(y)$. The level curves show $f(x,y) = k/16$ for $0 \leq k \leq 16$. The black dots are the critical points $C_3 \times C_3$; the red dots demonstrate how every level curve contains $1$ or $2$ critical points.

[image]