# The Koch snow flake, Holder exponents of conformal mappings

Tags: cv.complex-variables, fractals

The Koch snow flake $K$ is a domain of $\mathbb{C}$, complex plane. Though, I do not state the precise definition, you can see the picture in wikipedia [Koch snow flake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake#/media/File:Von_Koch_curve.gif).

The Koch snow flake $K$ is a **quasidisk**. Let $\mathbb{D}$ be an open unit disk and let $\phi:\mathbb{D} \to K$ be a conformal mapping. It is known that $\phi$ and the inverse map $\phi^{-1}$ are Holder continuous: there exist $\alpha \in (0,1]$, $\beta \in (0,1]$, and $L_1,L_2 \in (0,\infty)$ such that 
\begin{align*}
|\phi(z_1)-\phi(z_2)| &\le L_1 |z_1-z_2|^{\alpha},\quad z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{D}, \\
|\phi^{-1}(w_1)-\phi^{-1}(w_2)| &\le L_2 |w_1-w_2|^{\beta},\quad w_1,w_2 \in K.
\end{align*}

**My question**

Is there a study for quantitative estimates on the Holder exponents $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

I think that there is such study because the Koch snow flake is a famous fractal set.

**ADD**

By an argument by Benoît Kloeckner, $\alpha$ must be less than or equal to $\log3 / \log 4$. Is there a reasonable lower bound for $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

**ADD2**

Let $C$ be a closed Jordan curve.

[Lasley](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24893092?read-now=1&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) considers the following condition on $C$.

> **Definition.** Let $w_1$ and $w_3$ be points on $C$ and let $w_2$
>    be on the arc of small diameter between $w_1$ and $w_3$. Then, $C$ is said to be a *$c$-quasiconformal curve* if there exist positive constants $c$ and $\delta$ such that
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{|w_1-w_2|+|w_2-w_3|}{|w_1-w_3|} \le c
> \end{align*}
>   for any such $w_1,w_2,w_3$ with $|w_1-w_3| \le \delta$.

Lasley prove

> **Theorem.** Suppose that $f$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ conformally onto the interior $\Omega$ of a $c$-quasiconformal curve $C$. Then, $f$ is
>   $\alpha$-Holder continuous. Here,
>   \begin{align*} \alpha=\frac{2
>  (\text{arcsin}(1/c))^2}{\pi^2 -\pi \text{arcsin}(1/c)}. 
> \end{align*}

If $\Omega=K$, the Koch snowflake, $c=\cdots$.

Comment: I would guess it's the same as the Holder exponent for mapping the unit circle onto the boundary of the snowflake, so $\alpha = \ln 2/\ln 3$ and $\beta = \alpha^{-1}$. But it's a bit outside my area of expertise.

Comment: @NikWeaver Thank you for your comment. Can you tell me a reference for the fact that the Holder exponent $\alpha$ for mapping the unit circle onto the boundary of the snowflake equals to $\log 2 /\log 3$. I didn't know that at all.

Comment: @NikWeaver: your guess for $\beta$ is too optimistic: having Hölder exponent greater than $1$ implies that the function is constant. For $\alpha$, you might be right, except that you should have written $\log 3/\log 4$ (there are $4$ images of scale $1/3$). $\alpha$ cannot be greater than this, that it can be achieved by a conformal map is not obvious.

Comment: @sharpe: that $\log 3/\log 4$ is a upper bound can be seen by looking at the dimensions: the image of a metric space of Hausdorff dimension $d$ by a $\alpha$-Hölder map has dimension at most $d/\alpha$ (this follows from the definitions). That it can be achieved by a map from the circle to the Von Koch boundary is, I think, done in Assouad's Bulletin SMF paper http://archive.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1983__111__429_0.pdf (in French).

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Maybe I understood. A conformal map $\phi : \mathbb{D} \to K$ is extended to a homeomorphism from $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ to $\bar{K}$. Since $\partial K$ is regarded as the image of the unit circle under $\phi$, we have $\log4 /\log 3 \le 1/\alpha$.  Hence, $\alpha \le \log3 /\log 4$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I also thank you for teaching me the paper. I do not know much French, but I will read it.

Comment: @BenoitKloeckner: yes, I meant $\ln 3/\ln 4$ --- in fact (embarrassingly) this correct value is given in my book Lipschitz Algebras (second edition). Sharpe, on p. 68 of this book there is a brief discussion of this example, in case that helps.

Comment: @NikWeaver Thank you for your information.

Comment: @sharpe the extension to an heomorphism of the boudary should be checked carfeully (for general domains, boundaries need not be topological circles, think of a slit disk for example), but yes that is the idea I had in mind.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Thank you for your reply. I understood.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner In fact "Hölder exponent greater than 1 implies that the function is constant" holds for functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, or even on a length space, but I think  it is not true here, due to the fact that any arc of $K$ has infinite length. In fact I think one can take $\beta=1/\alpha=\log4/\log3$  (so these exponents are also sharp)

Comment: @PietroMajer: it is true that my affirmation is not universally true, but since here we consider a map from the *domain* delimited by the von Koch curve, it does apply.

Comment: Yes sorry, I had misread the question, and in fact I thought I had deleted my comment, but for some reason I failed again :/

Comment: @all Today, I found an interesting paper by F. D. Lesley. So, I update the contents of my question.

Answer (score 5):

U.R Freiberg and M.R. Lancia, [Energy Form on a Closed Fractal Curve](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4928/071439ea10140b21dd0a0ccd124812c84f31.pdf) (2004):

*The Koch snow flake is the union of three Koch curves of Hausdorff dimension $D=\ln 4/\ln 3$ and Hölder exponent $\beta=\log 2/\log 3$.*

See Proposition 2.2, attributed to a [1999 paper](https://iris.uniroma1.it/handle/11573/243201#.XSB1Sy2B3OQ) which I did not find online.

(For reference, Pietro Majer's argument for $\alpha=\log 3/\log 4$ is in this 2016 [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/258147/11260).)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. U.R Freiberg and M.R. Lancia show in Prop 2.2 that the domain of the energy from on Koch curve (not on Koch snow flake) is continuously embedded into the space of Holder continuous functions with exponent $\log2/\log3$. However, does this result lead us to an estimate of the Holder exponents of conformal mappings $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$?

Comment: @sharpe, Carlo, a copy of the paper of Vivaldi and Lancia, though of not so high  graphical quality, can be found [here](http://media.accademiaxl.it/memorie/S5-VXXIII-P1-2-1999/Lancia-Vivaldi101-116.pdf).

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thank you for showing me the paper by Vivaldi and Lancia. But, I do not know how to use it. By using their results, we can just see $\beta \le \log2/\log3$.

Comment: Why can you deduce $\beta \ge \log2/ \log3$?